# How do I use an array to speed up this process?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to assign and store two calculated values to a single scenario ("i") in an array. Then I want to dump one of those values (for each "i") in one column and the other value in another column, once the loops are completed. If you look under 'UI, that's what I want to essentially accomplish, but I want them all to spit out at once after the loops are completed, instead of each one spitting out one at a time. I heard an array would be the best/fastest way to do this, but I don't know how to even go about using one.

Thanks

```
 Sub Test_Scenarios()

    Dim i As Long, Scenario_Count As Long
    Dim j As Integer


    'Delete current values on "Testing Output" tab
    Sheets("Testing Output").Range("B1:B3").ClearContents
    Sheets("Testing Output").Range("A6:AA1000000").ClearContents

    'Test scenarios
    Scenario_Count = Sheets("Testing Input").Range("B1").Value

        For i = 1 To Scenario_Count

        For j = 1 To 2
            If j = 1 Then Sheets("AA").Range("ZC").Value = "No"
            If j = 2 Then Sheets("AA").Range("ZC").Value = "Yes"

        Calculate

            'UI
            If j = 1 Then Sheets("Testing Output").Range("R" & 5 + i).Value = Sheets("User Input").Range("B26").Value
            If j = 2 Then Sheets("Testing Output").Range("S" & 5 + i).Value = Sheets("User Input").Range("B26").Value

         Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to add a tag to your question to say which language you are asking about as many programming languages have arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good discussion of using Arrays to with Excel ranges at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx, but I'll include some basics here.

To read data from an Excel Range in to an array:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("A1:B10")
```

To write data from an array to an Excel Range:

```
Range("E1:F10").Value = Arr
```

When writing the array back to the range, the size of the array must match the size of the Range. You can check the size of the array using UBound:

```
myRange.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2))
```

You access data in the array by specifying the position in each dimension:

```
Arr(2, 3) = 7
```

Edit due to extra info about the question:

The example below creates an empty array and sizes it according to the number of scenarios, then stores values as it goes through the loop. The values from the loop are written to the output range after the loops are complete:

```
Option Base 1
Sub Test_Scenarios()

    Dim i As Long, Scenario_Count As Long
    Dim j As Integer


    'Delete current values on "Testing Output" tab
    Sheets("Testing Output").Range("B1:B3").ClearContents
    Sheets("Testing Output").Range("A6:AA1000000").ClearContents

    'Test scenarios
    Scenario_Count = Sheets("Testing Input").Range("B1").Value

    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(Scenario_Count, 2)
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Set outputRange = Sheets("Testing Output").Range("R5")
    Set outputRange = outputRange.Resize(Scenario_Count, 2)

    For i = 1 To Scenario_Count

        For j = 1 To 2
            'Calculate
            Sheets("User Input").Range("B26").Value = Sheets("User Input").Range("B26").Value + i + j

            'UI
            arr(i, j) = Sheets("User Input").Range("B26").Value
            Debug.Print "i: " & i & " j: " & j & " value: " & arr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    outputRange.Value = arr

End Sub
```

The loops are still reading and writing to the spreadsheet, as we don't have any other information about the calculations.

Comment: I understand all of those basics you've provided and I have done a lot of research as well. I just don't know how to make an array that corresponds to the data I have. Most posted examples are fairly easy to understand but they don't seem to do what I want mine to do. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: @Moy2 Sorry, I misunderstood when you mentioned that you didn't know how to use an array. Could you explain a little more about where you need to get the data from and where you need to write it out?

Comment: No problem, it's my fault for not explaining myself. Yes, so I have a workbook with multiple sheets of data. Through a large process I come down to a calculation/rate that I need based what scenario I run. Each scenario ("i") has specific criteria in changing that calculation. Well for each scenario I run, I need two different rates ("j=1, j=2"). I was wondering if there was a way I could use an array to store those two rates for each scenario, and spit them all out at once, after the loops are completed, in two different ranges. Right now, the rates are spitting out one scenario at a time.

Comment: When I say spitting out, I mean writing to an excel sheet. I am running close to 90,000 scenarios during my test. Each scenario is a little bit different and needs two separate calculations/rates. My goal is to speed up this test and make it more efficient. I heard an array would help do that.

Comment: Arrays are data containers, you put the data in the array, you work on it, you take the data out of the array.  I'm not sure what you're thinking an array does but typically you don't put your variables in an array unless you have a whole table of variables.  Without knowing what your "calcuate" process is its impossible to give you an array version of the code because that is the part that would have to be addaped for the array.

Comment: I know arrays are data containers. I'm asking is there a way I can write data (the calculated rates) to the array for each scenario I run within the loop, have the array constantly store/save that data for each scenario, and then write all that contained data out to an excel range once the loop is finished? Or does an array not work that way? Thank you for all your help and I apologize for my lack of knowledge and my miscommunication.